# Changing the C code for desired Output

Tags: c

I have came across this interview question. I know it's tricky but can't think of any approach.

Change the program so that the output of printf is always `20`. Only `foo()` can be changed. `main()` function can not be changed.

```
   void foo()
   {
       // Add Here
   }

   int main()
   {
      int i = 20;
      foo();
      i = 100;
      printf("%d", i);
      //Some other computation. Doesn't have any printf statements.
      return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use Macro Arguments to change the output of printf.

```
void foo()
{
    #define printf(x, y) printf(x, 20);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 20;
    foo();
    i = 100;
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

By using this, during `printf("%d",i)` will get mapped to macro expansion `printf("%d",20)`

Comment: I was going to say `#define printf(...) puts("20")`

Answer (score 1):

foo() could merely print 20 and call exit().